# Ubuntu 20.04 does not recognize Mi A2 phone over USB, but recognizes other Xiaomi Devices

Tags: usb, phone

I'm having a weird problem that I have no idea on possible solutions. I bought a Xiaomi Mi A2 to do some Android development, and both Ubuntu Machines I have here (Both desktop and laptop) can't recognize the phone.

It shows as charging, but `lsusb` does not show the devices.

I have another Xiaomi phone here (Pocophone F1) that appears as normal.

I know that it can be a hardware problem, but my idea is to test some tips before returning the device and getting another one.

`lsusb` with Pocophone F1:

```
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0480:0900 Toshiba America Inc MQ04UBF100
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.1 Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:5418 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 3-Port USB 2.1 Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 3-Port USB 2.1 Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0bda:4937 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB2.0 Microphone
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0951:16b7 Kingston Technology HyperX Alloy FPS Mechanical Gaming Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:1939 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c53f Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 2717:ff40 Xiaomi Inc. Mi/Redmi series (MTP)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsusb` with Mi A2:

```
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0480:0900 Toshiba America Inc MQ04UBF100
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.1 Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:5418 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 3-Port USB 2.1 Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 3-Port USB 2.1 Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0bda:4937 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB2.0 Microphone
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0951:16b7 Kingston Technology HyperX Alloy FPS Mechanical Gaming Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:1939 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c53f Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Tried enabling / disabling developer mode and usb debugging, also tried to boot in fastboot mode, changing cables, cleaning the usb c connector, etc. Nothing helped.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect the phone.

Comment: I tried on a old windows machine that I have here and same problem, it does not get recognized. Pretty sure that is a hardware problem at this level, will look for a replacement. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a hardware issue.